# how to add List to Array List in android?

Tags: java, android, telephony, telephonymanager

I am getting the `getNeighboringCellInfo()` using `TelephonyManager`  .I want list out the neighboringcells details in the **listview**.I successfully getting the neighboringcells but I could't display in the list view Please help me solve this problem.

```
listedSignals = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listSignals);

private void getNeighbors(TelephonyManager telephonyManager) throws InterruptedException {
   List<NeighboringCellInfo> neighboringCellInfos;
   neighboringCellInfos = telephonyManager.getNeighboringCellInfo();
   neighboringCellBlockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(100);
   for (int i = 0;i < neighboringCellInfos.size();i++) {
       NeighboringCellInfo info = neighboringCellBlockingQueue.poll(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       ArrayList<NeighboringCellInfo> cellInfoList = new ArrayList<>(neighboringCellBlockingQueue.size() + 1);
       while (info != null) {
           cellInfoList.add(info);
           info = neighboringCellBlockingQueue.poll(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       }
       neighboringCellInfos = cellInfoList;
   }
}
```

the `neighboringCellInfos` have the details of all neighboring cells.So please tell me using `neighboringCellInfos` in the `listedSignals`listview.

Comment: First of all you should move `ArrayList<NeighboringCellInfo> cellInfoList = new ArrayList<>(neighboringCellBlockingQueue.size() + 1);` out of the for loop because that gets created again everytime inside the for loop, resetting the previous added value to nothing again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an `adapter` specific to the information you want to display in your `ListView` (there are [many examples of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view) already here on SO). With your own custom adapter you're able to define what information you want displayed within your `ListView`. Once you've done that you simply add your list to your adapter and set the `adapter` of your `ListView` in your activity like so:

```
CustomListAdapter myAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, cellInfoList, ...);
listedSignals.setListAdapter(myAdapter);
```